# BSD - write(1) uid's

Tags: bash, sudo, uid

In bash, `write(1)` takes in `user` as an arg and then takes input to send to `user` as a message. When trying it out myself I can run

```
user$ write $USER
// Message from user@ubuntu on pts/1 at 12:34 ...
```

at which point <kbd>Enter</kbd> delimited input is echoed back to `user`

As a test, I ssh'ed into `user` in a separate window then executed

```
user$ sudo su user2
user2$ write user
// write: you are uid 1003, but your login is as uid 1001
```

I expected to start writing to `user`

## Questions

How does `write(1)` know I am logged in as a different user?

Can I login with `sudo` so that my uid's are the same?

Where are the different uid's stored? Is it sudo_uid vs uid maybe?

Thank you !!

Comment: Read the source to find out. That said, `write` is completely independent of `bash`, it's the same in any shell. See e.g. the output of `which write`, which allows you to distinguish between shell builtin commands and programs.

Comment: I knew it was a program, I just did this in bash so I thought I'd include that